# Strict monotonic solution to ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ continuous differentiable and let $\psi : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a soultion to $y' = f(y)$ in the open interval $I$, if there is $a \in I$ such that $f(\psi(a)) > 0$ then $ \psi$ is strictly monotonic ?

I think that since $f$ is continuous differentiable then by Picard there is unique solution, so if we used the fact that $ f(\psi(b)) \leq  0$ creates a second solution then we have contradiction, but i don't know how !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an equilibrium point $f(p)=0$ one possible solution is always the stationary function $x(t) = p$ for all $t$. It then follows from Picard's theorem of local existence and uniqueness that a non-constant solution can't cross any equilibrium points. That is if $f(x(t)) \neq 0$ for at least one $t$, then $f(x(t)) \neq 0$ for all $t$. Now notice that $f \circ x: I \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function. If $f\circ x$ takes positive and negative values then it must also take the value $0$ by the intermediate value theorem. But this is impossible if $x$ is non–constant, as we have seen before. Hence, if $x$ is a nonconstant integral curve of a field $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then $\dot x = f \circ x$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative and $x$ is monotone.

Comment: I've written $x: I \to \mathbb R$ instead of  $\psi$ for the solution of the ODE, since it is the standard notation.